# Set CPU Affinity in PHP?

Tags: php, linux, process, affinity

Pretty straightforward question - is there a way to set the CPU affinity via PHP?  Any of the following will do:

- Setting the affinity of the current process via a PHP call.
- Setting the affinity of a specific PID via a PHP call.
- As a last resort, setting the affinity of a specific PID via a command-line tool.

The only option I've found so far is the last one, using a tool named schedutils, and it seems it may only be supported on more recent kernels.

[Schedutils](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/setting-processor-affinity-certain-task-or-process.html)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why should PHP be screwing around with the web server in this way?

Comment: I've found that certain long-running tasks on our server become resource hogs.  I'm exploring different options for effectively "niceing" a PHP script (beyond "nice" and CLI PHP, obviously :) ).  If you have other ideas, I'd love to hear them!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to set the CPU affinity is with the `sched_setaffinity` C function. It's not available through the standard PHP API so you probably would have to write an extension.

An alternative is running `taskset` program through `system`. For example this binds the PHP process to cores 0 and 1:

```
system('taskset -cp 0,1 '.getmypid());
```